# What's the correct way to execute multiple Google Cloud Functions with different outgoing IPs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I intend to use Google Cloud Functions to access an API. My goal is to use several functions, each with a different IP address. I would be distributing processing across several functions simultaneously that would then each interact with the target API. As I understand it, there's the possibility that the execution of two separate functions could be take place on the same machine - meaning requests would originate from the IP. In order to respect the rate limits, I need to know how many requests will be going through each IP address and therefore need to ensure that each function is executing with a separate IP.

I'm new to Google Cloud Functions, but I've made some progress. Currently, I have a function `function-1`. This function is using `connector-1` and passing all egress traffic through my default VPC network. I followed the guide provided by Google Cloud for [associating a static IP with my function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip). As a result, I now have `router-1` which is connected with my NAT gateway `nat-1`. Finally, `nat-1` has a static IP associated with it.

At this point, any execution of `function-1` is using the static IP as expected. However, I'm still trying to understand the proper way of structuring this. I have a few questions on the matter:

- Do I have to duplicate every link in the chain for each function that requires its own IP address?
- Am I able to re-use some of these items? For example, perhaps all functions can use the same VPC network?
- Is there a better way to structure things to meet my requirements assuming I needed 10 or 20 functions using different IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers:

- I'm not sure what you mean with "duplicate every link in the chain", but if you want to enforce each CF to have a static IP address you will have to follow the [steps you shared](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip).
- Yes, you could re-use the VPC network and attach a new serverless VPC connector. Even in the same region.
- If you want to force a different static IP for each CF, no, you need to follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip).

As a tip, you can use [`gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/vpc-access/connectors/create) to kind of automatize the connectors creation. It may be useful if you have to create many because it's faster than using the Console.

If this limitation does not suit your scenario you should wonder whether this is the appropriate product for you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Apologies for my lack of clarity. By "duplicate every link in the chain" I was essentially asking if every single component (the VPC, connector, router, etc) would need created for every single IP I require. I appreciate your insight and will consider if another solution is better suited to my needs than Cloud Functions.

Comment: Okay. However if you feel that an answer has helped you and may help others you should accept it. This way a question may be found more easily by somebody who is having the same doubts.

Comment: You got it. I just like to wait a little to see if anyone else answers, but I've accepted your answer. Thank you.